# Bad words regex filter not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get a bad words filter to work. So far, with the code below, no filtering happens if I type a bad word like "bad1" listed in array below and I get this error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ‘/’

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

// Words not allowed
$disallowedWords = array(
'bad1',
'bad2',
);
// Search for disallowed words.
// The Regex used here should e.g. match 'are', but not match 'care'
foreach ($disallowedWords as $word) {
if (preg_match("/\s+$word\s+/i", $entry)) {
die("The word '$word' is not allowed...");
}
}

// Variable contains a regex that will match URLs

$urlRegex = '/(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-
9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]
{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1
-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost
|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.
(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-z
A-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*/';

// Search for URLs
if (preg_match($urlRegex, $entry)) {
die("URLs are not allowed...");
}

}
```

Comment: Why match it that way. You can check for matches with http://php.net/strpos. As to your question the regex fails because you are requiring white space on both side. You want `\s*` but then `notbadword` would also match...

Comment: You have two issues, missed the error message at first. That is from your delimiters. Check URL checker regex.

Comment: I would use this regex: /\b$word\b/i, because it will match bad words at the end and at the beginning of string too, not just between words...

Comment: `preg_quote()` for the words list. The error actually stems from unescaped `/` delimiters in the URL regex. Escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way of matching the words. Use this regex in your foreach loop.

```
preg_match("#\b" . $word . "\b#", $entry);
```

You can also test your regular expressions [here](http://www.regexr.com/). Use `/\bbad1\b/g`.

The code put in action:

```
<?php
// delete the line below in your code
$entry = "notbad1word bad1 bad notbad1.";

$disallowedWords = array(
    'bad1',
    'bad2',
);

foreach ($disallowedWords as $word)
{ // use $_POST['text'] instead of $entry
    preg_match("#\b". $word ."\b#", $entry, $matches); 
    if(!empty($matches))
        die("The word " . $word . " is not allowed.");
}

echo "All good.";
```

This code doesn't match `notbad1word` or `notbad2word` (and so on) but matches only `bad1` or `bad2`.

As to your urlRegex, you have to escape `/` with `\` like this: `\/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a slow loop:

```
<?php

$_POST['text'] = 'This sentence uses the nobad1 bad2 word!';

if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

    // Words not allowed
    $disallowedWords = array(
        'bad1',
        'bad2',
    );

    $pattern = sprintf('/(\\s%s\\s)/i', implode('\\s|\\s',$disallowedWords));
    $subject = ' '.$_POST['text'].' ';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $token)) {
        die(sprintf("The word '%s' is not allowed...\n", trim($token[1])));
    }
}
```

You have to make sure that the catalog of words does not contain any characters of `/`, `(` or `)`.

Comment: I am wrong to think this is going to match `notbad1` in the string too?

Comment: @jvitasek And the OP said where that this should not occur?

Comment: @jvitasek Yes, but it is the OPs system, not yours. You do not know what the OP wants. At least you should not assume you do. A common mistake...

Comment: A common mistake is not to read the question. It explicitly states in a comment `// The Regex used here should e.g. match 'are', but not match 'care'`

Comment: @jvitasek You are right there. Thanks for pointing that out. How good that I already added a version that considers that.

Comment: This works nicely and is much more clean and simple. Do you advise I stick the redirect to the form on the same page be added right after the die line?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `/` as delimiting character, but don't escape its "inner" occurences:

```
$urlRegex = '/(http|https|ftp)\://whatever/';
//                               ^ Unknown modifier ‘/’
```

Either change the delimiter, or escape the slashes.

As to your "bad words" filter:

1. It will fail to recognize words at the beginning and end of the string. Consider using `\b` (word boundary) instead of `\s+`.
2. If any of the bad words in your array has an unescaped regex character, the results might be unexpected. Consider using `preg_quote` on each word from the array.
3. *n* `preg_match` calls for *n* words is not very efficient. I'd recommend imploding the words array into a single regex like `'/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/i'`.