# Issue with bad words filter

Tags: php, regex

I am having an issue with this bad word prevention code. If I leave it as is below the code will say "the word bad1 is not allowed" no matter what I type.
If i remove the line 4th line below with the $entry variable, then the code lets everything pass, even bad1.

The goal is to match words like 'are', but not match 'care'

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

// delete the line below in your code
$entry = "notbad1word bad1 bad notbad1.";

$disallowedWords = array(
'bad1',
'bad2',
);

foreach ($disallowedWords as $word)
{ // use $_POST['text'] instead of $entry
preg_match("#\b". $word ."\b#", $entry, $matches); 
if(!empty($matches))
    die("The word " . $word . " is not allowed.&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><a
 href=\"javascript:history.back();\">Go Back</a></b>");
}
}
```

This code below works fine and was what I accepted originally as an answer (I can just stick with this but it won't do anything for interior matching I don't think). Anyway, if there isn't a quick fix, I will be content with the below answer that I originally accepted:

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

// Words not allowed
$disallowedWords = array(
    'bad1',
    'bad2',
);

$pattern = sprintf('/(%s)/i', implode('|',$disallowedWords));
$subject = $_POST['text'];
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $token)) {
    die(sprintf("The word '%s' is not allowed. &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><a
 href=\"javascript:history.back();\">Go Back</a></b>\n", $token[1]));
}
}
```

Comment: So, why did you accept this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29188458/ in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29188299/ ? What's different with this one?

Comment: You need to clarify what needs to be matched. As the `\b` flag sets the boundary, meaning it won't pick up `notbad1word`/`notbad1`. Do you want to pick those up? What do you want to do? We need more info.

Comment: I accepted a different version of the answer at first because it worked fine, but I read the comments that this way was better in terms of matching just as I wanted. But I just got around to implementing and reallzed it doesn't work as written. The idea was to match bad words 'are', but not match 'care' etc